# cgminer api-allow using dns instead of IP address

Tags: cgminer

I am wondering why cgminer is not accepting dns instead of IP addresses

I need to allow a server by it's dns...is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify, as I do not understand how you would use domain name servers for this. Do you mean you would like to use a domain (e.g. example.com) to connect?

Comment: I would like to use a DNS in the --api-allow command and not IP, so i can control my machine with my dynamic ip address of my other machine, i have set up a noip.com dynamic dns, but the --api-allow don't work for some reason if it's not getting an IP

Comment: It's probably a bad idea anyway, since then anyone who compromised your noip account (or any crooked noip sysadmin) could point your domain to themself and then take control of your miner.

Answer (score 1):

cgminer accepts domain names for me, It's all I have used, never have I used an IP. I would check and make sure your URI is correct if DNS is working for you in your web browser and such.

Here is an example of a URI for stratum
stratum+tcp://[serveraddress/domain]:[port]

The cgminer command would be:
./cgminer -o stratum+tcp://[serveraddress/domain]:[port] -u [username] -p [password]

If you want to test it on another pool, try this command below and try mining a couple shares on Eligius, there's no registration, just use your btc address as username and "x" for password
cgminer -o stratum+tcp://stratum.mining.eligius.st:3334 -u YourBitcoinAddress -p x

Maybe you could copy and paste some of the error messages you were getting to help further diagnose this?

Comment: it's working fine with DNS's in the pool config, i am talking about the --api-allow command